# Using Ms Word in ios or android app

Tags: android, ios, ms-word, office365

Is there a way to add ms word to android or ios app to create or edit word document like cloudon app in Google play and app store. So does anyone knows how cloudon app works maybe using an api or office 365

Comment: There's no easy way, in terms of putting word inside your app, they don't have that sort of API.  The closest you could come would be something like sending an intent to the office app.  Or, *an* office app, I mean...

Comment: @KristopherMicinski There's an API, i.e. Apache POI. Although it's an Apache project and not an MS project, still it's an API that can be used and is already used in many projects.

Comment: @MathiasLin I was speaking to an MS sponsored API...

Answer (score 2):

There's an open source java lib "Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents" at http://poi.apache.org/, but never tested it myself on Android though (but in other web java projects); but I guess it would also work on there.

With that, you can read/write office documents, thus also editing them.

Comment: +1. You answer the question, although the idea dosen't make much sense (the one in the question).

Comment: @Linuxios Well I wouldn't write such an app either, but that's what he asked. I'm not a MS Office user, but afaik MS Word also supports html, or at least their latest version saves in html? Not sure, but depending how much control he has over the documents, he could also use html format entirely, but still open/save it in MS Office, sort of. And depending a bit on the complexity of the documents. But you're answer is also good actually, I just voted it up.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm an open source guy, and a agree with the FSF on most things, Office being one of them. I happen to be rather pushy when it comes to suggesting to *not* use Office, .NET, Windows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, and so is the long answer. Microsoft Word is a proprietary Office suite for Windows, Mac, and Windows Phone. It could only be used on other OSes directly if Microsoft ported it. You could look at the MS Office document reading and writing code in an open source suite (such as LibreOffice) and base your code on that.

Or, and this is the practical answer, use a format that you have libraries for or can write code for. I don't know about Android, but iOS has PDF support in Core Graphics. And there are standards for formats that you could use for a document application. Here are a couple:

- PDF: Probably already a library for it.
- HTML: Any HTML/XML library will do, and it can already be rendered by embeding the target system's WebKit.
- RTF: I'm not sure how open it is, but it's not binary.
- ODT: Most complicated, but most feature full. And you might even be able to port some of the LibreOffice code
- Any other markup language: You can create your own format, but you also have to render it yourself.

Just remember this: The only program that will always support all of Microsoft Office documents is Microsoft Office, and I'm also not sure how Apple would like it if you submitted an App that uses Office docs as it's primary format.

Comment: But cloudon uses ms office to edit and create do you have any idea how

Comment: @mrl25: Here's what I think they do. They have a Windows Server that runs MS Office, Photoshop, and whatever other apps they offer (I'm sure they worked out special Licences with Microsoft and Adobe). YOu then get a almost remote access to those Word, PowerPoint, etc., instances. Why do yo think it's called cloudon?

Comment: @mrl25: Why's it so important that it be Office? Why can't you just use a better, open format like the ones I listed above?

Comment: I was asked to create an ios and android app just like cloudon uses ms office to create and edit word doc, ppt, and xsl and store it on online storage

Comment: @mrl25: So you we're asked to do that? Then you might want to have a conversation with the person who asked you to, or, tell them that you would have to write your own Office support, maybe that library above, or create a massive, expensive server to do what I think cloudon does.

Comment: I don’t think it’s an easy thing to do because I’ve tried using office 365 in my iphone browser and I could not edit the doc only view it. Any way thank you for your help

Comment: @mrl25: I know. Unfortunately, embedding things where they were never suposed to be is never easy.